# Is it possible to have 2 domains for 2 blogs on one server?

Tags: apache, dns

I have one vServer with apache2 that hosts 2 sites (Worpress blogs). They are physically located in /www/blog1 and /www/blog2. Now I have 2 domains domain1.com and domain2.com.

I want domain1.com to point to blog1 and domain2.com accordingly to blog2. The URLs should always include the appropriate domain. I do not want to use a simple redirect like domain2.com -> domain1.com/blog2.

I use domain1.com for different other purposes like SVN, email, wiki etc. domain2.com is reserved only for my blog. I do not know if this is relevant.

Users should not notice that my site is hosted somewhere else, at least the URL should not suggest that.

Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like what every shared hosting provider does. It is definitely possible.

Comment: "I've never beamed 3 people from 2 targets onto 1 pad before!" - Montgomery Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you are using Apache then look into using [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/). Specifically [name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) they allow you to separate websites and web roots based on the domain name used. Heres an example of one server hosting two sites www.domain.tld and www.otherdomain.tld:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
    DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

In this example files located in `/www/domain` would be served for www.domain.tld and the directory `/www/otherdomain` would only have files accessible on www.otherdomain.tld

Comment: I used this solution and it works fine. I pointed both domains (DNS entries) to the same IP address and modified the config files in /etc/apache2/sites-available accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "VirtualHost" to do that. See : [Apache 2 VirtalHost Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/)